# primes congruent to +-1 (mod 6)

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I'm currently reading **Discrete Mathematics: Elementary and Beyond of Springer Mathematical Series**; and come across a fact in the review questions that seems quite obvious, but difficult to prove.
It goes like:

**All prime numbers greater than 3 give remainder 1 or -1 when divided by 6.**

How about proving this?
 Won't it require us to know the general term, i.e. the formula for nth prime number?

Comment: Did you search this site at all?

Comment: somewhat...why?

Comment: Thanks for the link..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possibilities are
$$x\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5\bmod 6.$$

If $x \equiv 0 \bmod 6$ then $x$ is divisible by $6$ and so not prime.

If $x \equiv 2 \bmod 6$ or $x \equiv 4 \bmod 6$ then $x$ is divisible by $2$ and so not prime (unless $x=2$).

If $x \equiv 3 \bmod 6$ then $x$ is divisible by $3$ and so not prime (unless $x=3$).

So we are only left with $x \equiv 1 \bmod 6$ or $x \equiv 5 \equiv -1 \bmod 6$ if $x>3$ is prime.

Comment: The question asks for a proof, not a repetition of the statement.